# Go js tree auto position arrowheads

Tags: tree, gojs, arrows

I am using go js library to create a tree-like structure, my nodes are rectangular linked with the arrows.

If i manually update the name of nodes in JSON and re-render the gojs tree, the position of the arrows are disrupted, how do i maintain arrow position on renaming the tree nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You should let the **Diagram.layout** rearrange the nodes to accommodate their new sizes. This will automatically update the routes of any connected links.

But I am guessing that you do not have a **Diagram.layout** (or have set its **Layout.isInitial** property to false) *AND* you have saved all of the link routes in the model and have not updated those routes. Not updating those routes in the model is quite understandable, because it is difficult to compute and you do not know the new node sizes.

So I recommend that you remove in the model the link data's `points` property from those links connecting with nodes that have probably changed size. Then the diagram will automatically compute the standard link route given the link's property values.